# Access and modify clarion .dat file

Tags: clarion

Does anyone know how to access and edit the .dat clarion files? It seems that clarion is a database for DOS. the tables are stored in DAT files. I need to update few fields of that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple edit, you can use the CSCN.EXE utility. It's a DOS app, it runs in Windows 32 bits.
Download it [here](http://sca.mx/ftp/cscn.zip) (try F1).

For programmatic access, you'll need to develop something using [Clarion for Windows](http://softvelocity.com)